# Transfer msg with nodejs / socket.io to nodejs / express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm having trouble to let my application runs as I would like... What I'm looking to do is to send a message from socket.io client (emitter.js) to socket.io server (receiver.js) and then display the message on the page generated using Express/EJS (index.ejs)

What I've succeed to do so far is :

```
// receiver.js
// This script initiates a simple HTML page using Express/EJS
// and then wait for socket.io connection on port 3000
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {params: 'some_params'})
})

app.server = http.createServer(app)

var io = require('socket.io')(app.server)
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('init', 'Init OK !')
    console.log('init page ok')
    socket.on('new_data', function(msg) {
        console.log('socket.on received new data : ', msg)
        socket.emit('new_data', 'Test')
    })
})

app.server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Main app listening on port 3000')
})
```

And the attached index.ejs file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='new_msg'></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io()
        socket.on('init', function(msg) {
            console.log(msg)
            $('#new_msg').html(msg)
        })
        socket.on('new_data', function(msg) {
            console.log(msg)
            $('#new_msg').html(msg)
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Finally, the emitter.js script :

```
// emitter.js
// Open io on port 3000 and then send a msg
var io = require('socket.io-client')
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000')
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('new_data', 'some_new_data')
    console.log('Send some_new_data')
})
```

I then run the server using `node receiver.js`
The app starts, in the console I have the message : Main app listening on port 3000, and when I open a browser to http://localhost:3000, I can see the first message Init OK!

Thus, receiver.js can successfully emit to index.ejs !

Then I run the client using `node emitter.js`. In the console of the emitter I have the message 'send some_new_data' and in the console of the receiver I have the message 'socket.on received new data : some_new_data'.

Thus, emitter.js can successfully emit to receiver.js which can successfully receives it.

But, where my problem is, is that the last line `socket.emit('new_data', 'Test')` is not executed (or not working) as the HTML page is not refreshed at all....

So, I don't understand why the message is fired from receiver to index.ejs during initialisation but is not working after ??...

If anybody would have some ideas regarding this problem, any help would be very much appreciate !

Comment: I'm confused.  You have two node apps and a browser page?  And, one app sends a socket.io msg to the other node app.  Then, what do you want to happen after that?

Comment: When `receiver.js` receives the `new_data` message, it does `socket.emit('new_data', 'Test')`.  That just sends back to the socket (which is the other node app `emitter.js`) that sent the message.  That doesn't send to the web page.  Are you trying to broadcast to all connected web pages?  If so, you can do `io.emit('new_data', 'Test')`.

Comment: OMG, it just works like this !... Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for :-) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `receiver.js` receives the `new_data` message, it does:

```
socket.emit('new_data', 'Test')
```

That just sends back to the socket (which is the other node app `emitter.js`) that sent the message. That doesn't send to the web page.

If you are trying to broadcast to all connected web pages, then you can do that with:

```
io.emit('new_data', 'Test')
```

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 for your help, it does work very well now !